# get_profile in django template loop leads to many SQL requests

Tags: django, performance, django-templates

In a django template, when you do a loop to display profile informations for many users, you call get_profile, thus generating as many SQL request :

```
{% for user in users %}
{{ user.username }} : {{ user.get_profile.birth_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you have 50 users to display, it will generate 50 SQL requests to get the profile for each user.

Is there an elegant way to reduce the number of requests ?

EDIT :

The final goal was to manage a list a items where an item has a user object as attribute.
Example : Each question in stackoverflow has a user as a creator. How to list all recent questions while displaying the user profile informations in a minimum of SQL requests :

The template should be like that :

```
{% for question in recent_questions %}
{{ question.title }}
{{ question.body }}
{{ question.creator.username }}
{{ question.creator.get_profile.age }}
{{ question.creator.get_profile.country }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this will generate too many SQL requests ...

Answer (score 1):

I would write my own templatetag for this case,

```
@register.simpletag(takes_context=True)
def load_profiles(context,users):
    context['profiles']=ProfileClass.objects.select_related().filter(user__in=users)
    return ''
```

template:

```
{% load_profiles users %}
{% for one in profiles%}
    {{one.user.username}} : {{one.birth_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I put some precision in the question : In my case, looping on profiles is not possible

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) query. But I'm not sure if `.get_profile()` will use cached instance hit the db. In that case, I would suggest you to query for list of profiles in your view using `select_related` so that `profile.user` is cached and available and pass profile list to the template rather than users list.

Answer (score 0):

It is not particularly elegant, but you can use raw() in your view to get the data in one request :

```
users = User.objects.raw("SELECT **the data you want**, birth_date FROM auth_user,
    app_userprofile as p WHERE p.user_id=auth_user.id"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for profile in profiles  %}
{{ profile.user.username }} : {{ profile.birth_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I put some precision in the question : In my case, looping on profiles is not possible